# Can mathjax integrate with ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, integration, mathjax

I want to integrate mathjax with the ckeditor, is this possible? if yes, please help me out. I searched in internet but i didn't found anything helpful.

please do the needful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit dated but ran across a great coeditor sample integrating mathjax and coeditor: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/master/plugins/mathjax. Sample includes plugin implementation. Simple and basic but a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It integrates quite well with CKEditor 4.3 see [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_mathjax)
Install the Mathematical Formulas CKEditor plugin and be sure to set your path to the MathJax library. `config.mathJaxLib = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';` as per their instructions.

The plugin is [here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax)
Also note that you need the Widget, Line Utilities, Dialog, Clipboard plugins in your editor for the MathJax to work.

Answer (score -1):

after researching in the internet and with some examples and experiments, finally found that mathjax cannot be integrated inside the ck editor.